# Invalid x dimension error in spatial point interpolation?

Tags: python, gdal, interpolation, scipy.spatial

I have a point shapefile with altitude values. I have used gdal/ogr to open shapefile and read points(x,y) and altitude(z) values.

It showing error when I am trying to interpolate with scipy griddata modue.

I return back following error:
**raise ValueError("invalid number of dimensions in xi")**

Please take a look of my codes:

```
# imports
    from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
    import os
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import scipy.interpolate as il
    import numpy as np
    from itertools import cycle


    # obtaining xyz to interpolate
    a=[]        # to store all x valuesa
    b=[]        # to store all corresponding y values
    c=[]        # to store all corresponding z values
    # input output 
    shapefile = r"P:\May2014\Test\LielaisIV_Bp_Schichten.shp"
    outras=r"P:\Interpolatio_spline_with_bariers\outras.tif"
    ## opening a shape file
    DriverName = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")     
    dataSource = DriverName.Open(shapefile, 0)
    print dataSource
    layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
    srs= layer.GetSpatialRef()
    #looping through features to get geometry reference for each ........
    for i in range(0, layer.GetFeatureCount()):
        # Get the input Feature
        inFeature = layer.GetFeature(i)
        geom = inFeature.GetGeometryRef()
        x= geom.GetX()
        a.append(x)
        y= geom.GetY()
        b.append(y)
        z= inFeature.GetField("of_wth_01")
        c.append(z)
    # obtaining max and min extent
    xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax = [min(a),max(a),min(b),max(b)]

    #size of 1 m grid
    nx = (int(xmax - xmin)+1)
    ny = (int(ymax - ymin)+1)
    # Generate a regular grid to interpolate the data.
    xi = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)#, endpoint=False)
    yi = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
    xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
    # Interpolate the values of z for all points in the rectangular grid
    zi = il.griddata((x, y), c, (xi, yi),method='linear')
```

Does anyone have any idea why diention error ocuurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the call to `il.griddata`.

```
# Interpolate the values of z for all points in the rectangular grid
zi = il.griddata((x, y), c, (xi, yi),method='linear')
#                 ^  ^
```

You use `x` and `y` which are single values (not lists). These two variables are last defined in the loop to extract the geometry from the shapefile.
You should replace `x` and `y` with `a` and `b`, the lists holding all the geometry data.